# Using linq to entity to make a nested query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-fluent-api

I have following classes:

```
public class A
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public ICollection<B> Bs {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public ICollection<C> Cs {get; set;}
}

public class C
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and these `ViewModels`:

```
public class AViewModel
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public ICollection<BViewModel> BViewModels {get; set;}
}
public class BViewModel
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public ICollection<CViewModel> CViewModels {get; set;}
}
public class CViewModel
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to write a `linq to entity` query(`Fluent API`) to find an `A` object by its `Id` that result is a `AViewModel` with a list of `BViewModel`s and each `BViewModel` include a list of `CViewModels`  too, 
I wrote following query but it has some errors:

```
 _uow.Repository<A>()
                .All()
                .Include("Bs")
                .Include("Bs.Cs")
                .Select(a => new AViewModel
                {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    Id = a.Id,
                    (ICollection<BViewModel>) 
                    a.Bs
                    .SelectMany(
                    t => a.Bs
                        .Select(r => new BViewModel()
                    {
                        Name = r.Name
                        Cs = 
                        (ICollection<CViewModel>)
                        t.Cs.SelectMany(y => new CViewModel()
                        {
                            Name = y.Name
                        })
                     }
                     )
                )
                }
                ).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == 5);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the `SelectMany` with `Select` and the type cast `(ICollection)` with `ToList()`.

```
_uow.Repository<A>()
    .All()
    .Select(a => new AViewModel
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Name = a.Name,
        Bs = a.Bs.Select(b => new BViewModel
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,
            Cs = b.Cs.Select(c => new CViewModel
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name
            }).ToList()
         }).ToList()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == Id);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you filter before you project (won't that be a bit performant - although probably optimized by the query provider.. but still)?

Comment: @LewsTherin, the OP code doesn't show any filter other than the last part.. `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: I think I understand what you meant, you think that doing `ToList()` inside `Select` is not convertable to L2S , right? The projection is done against ViewModel entity, not EF entity, it works fine.

Comment: Well, no. But that could be optimized by not calling `ToList()` I would have thought. 
My main question is, select projects every record in the repository right -e specially as he is calling `All()` - not needed as well (I think)? So I believe n-1 objects are created that won't even be used. Won't it be better to filter to the one specific object and project that? `.Where().Select()`

Comment: Well, actually the expression will be converted to linq query, something like [this](http://pastebin.com/jwHwqr1H), then it will be mapped to appropriate property, EF will do relationship fix-up when constructing `BViewModel` entity and map it to related `AViewModel::Bs`, and so does `CViewModel`, so the `ToList` is not actually execute the query, it's still deferred execution

Comment: Did you write that yourself or generate it?

Comment: I tried on my console using similar entities, and copy the result from sql profiler, here the [code](http://pastebin.com/P1DbgU0x) if you want to try it